# `group_by` and keep grouping levels as nested data frame's name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This question is related to and inspired by [can't use emmeans inside map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576160/cant-use-emmeans-inside-map)

I am doing several steps of data analysis with the following code. I want to keep my grouping factor's levels as the nested data frames' names and uses those names to identify each of the steps along the way, instead of using the default enumeration [[1]], [[2]], [[3]], etc. I don't understand the error I got. Please see how I can fix my code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(emmeans)
data("warpbreaks")
wb_emm <-  warpbreaks %>%
  group_by(tension) %>% 
  setNames(unique(.x$tension)) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~glm(breaks~wool,data=.x))) %>%
  mutate(jt = map(models, ~emmeans::joint_tests(.x, data = .x$data))) %>%
  mutate(means=map(models,~emmeans::emmeans(.x,"wool",data=.x$data))) %>%
  mutate(p_cont = map(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.x, "pairwise",infer = c(T,T))))

Error in unique(.x$tension) : object '.x' not found
```

I originally did `group_by(tension) %>% setNames(unique(tension))` and got `Error in unique(tension) : object 'tension' not found`
I also tried `split(.$tension)` but it is conflicted with `nest()`

But the `tension` levels are legible.

```
 unique(warpbreaks$tension)
[1] L M H
Levels: L M H
```

The code runs well without the `setNames(unique(.x$tension)) %>%` step.

```
wb_emm$p_cont
[[1]]
 contrast estimate   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 A - B        16.3 6.87 Inf      2.87      29.8 2.378   0.0174 

Confidence level used: 0.95 

[[2]]
 contrast estimate   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 A - B       -4.78 4.27 Inf     -13.1      3.59 -1.119  0.2630 

Confidence level used: 0.95 

[[3]]
 contrast estimate   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 A - B        5.78 3.79 Inf     -1.66      13.2 1.523   0.1277 

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Thank you.

Update: from the second solution provided by Ronak Shah below, I tried on `diamonds` but the names were unchanged. The code runs with either `ungroup()%>%` or `ungroup%>%`.

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~glm(price ~ x + y + z + clarity + color,data=.x)),
         jt = map(models, ~emmeans::joint_tests(.x, data = .x$data)),
         means=map(models,~emmeans::emmeans(.x,"color",data=.x$data)),
         p_cont = map(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.x, "pairwise",infer = c(T,T))),
         across(models:p_cont, stats::setNames,  .$cut)) -> diamond_result
> diamond_result$jt
[[1]]
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 x            1 Inf 611.626 <.0001 
 y            1 Inf   2.914 0.0878 
 z            1 Inf 100.457 <.0001 
 clarity      7 Inf 800.852 <.0001 
 color        6 Inf 256.796 <.0001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `setNames` in the `map` step :

```
library(tidyverse)

warpbreaks %>%
  group_by(tension) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~glm(breaks~wool,data=.x)),
        jt = map(models, ~emmeans::joint_tests(.x, data = .x$data)),
        means=map(models,~emmeans::emmeans(.x,"wool",data=.x$data)),
        p_cont = setNames(map(means, 
                  ~emmeans::contrast(.x, "pairwise",infer = c(T,T))),.$tension))
```

If you want to name all the list output use `across` :

```
warpbreaks %>%
  group_by(tension) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(models=map(data,~glm(breaks~wool,data=.x)),
         jt = map(models, ~emmeans::joint_tests(.x, data = .x$data)),
         means=map(models,~emmeans::emmeans(.x,"wool",data=.x$data)),
         p_cont = map(means, ~emmeans::contrast(.x, "pairwise",infer = c(T,T))),
         across(models:p_cont, setNames,  .$tension)) -> result

result$jt

#$L
# model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
# wool         1 Inf   5.653 0.0174 


#$M
# model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
# wool         1 Inf   1.253 0.2630 


#$H
# model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
# wool         1 Inf   2.321 0.1277
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I want to name all the nested df consistently. The second solution looks more efficient but it doesn't work on my end. `> wb_emm$jt
[[1]]
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 wool         1 Inf   5.653 0.0174 `

Comment: It works fine for me. Notice that I have assigned the value to `result` at the end of the pipe. So you should use `result$jt` to check. `wb_emm$jt` I guess is showing you output from your original code.

Comment: Thank you for the fix. I noticed the `-> result` but I just copy the code up to `.$tension))`. Here is what the new code gave me `> result$jt
[[1]]
 model term df1 df2 F.ratio p.value
 wool         1 Inf   5.653 0.0174`. Other than `tidyverse` and the packages I included, what else do you use for this problem?

Comment: I don't use anything else. Do you get any warnings or errors in the console? Can you update your post to include the exact code that you used? Also can you specify the package for `setNames` i.e `stats::setNames`

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I don't see any error. I tried another data set but I got the same result. The result is quite long so I've updated my question.

Comment: @hnguyen Ok...I got it. I think you have `plyr` loaded in the environment which is masking `mutate` and other functions and causing this behaviour. Restart R and load only `dplyr` or use `dplyr::mutate` and it should work fine. I think you loaded more libraries than what you have shown.